# How to click a element based on href text?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using C# I was trying to click on a element that has this text:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://client.mysite.com/nimda/settings.php?campaign=level+1;uid=vmrgssaxs8wkb45oy77pl5xuu&amp;id=172806#rotate"><img alt="Click to edit the rotator settings" title="Click to edit the rotator settings" src="../gfx/icons/small/rotation.png"></a>
```

so I tried to use this expression:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(@href, 'level 1')]")).Click();
```

but I get invalid expression , why ?

Note that I want to use xpath because there are many a elements in the page and all has same attributes except for href value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the brackets

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'level 1')]")).Click();
```

By the way, you can find element by the `href` attribute using `CssSelector`

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='level 1']")).Click();
```

Comment: I had to write value like `level+1`